# Metaproperties python

Tags: class, python-3.8

Is there a way to share setter for property values of a class? Let's say I have a simple class with two properties `a`, `b` and I want to have the same setter for them, how would I chain the decorators to make it work?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a = 1, b = 0):
        self.a = a
#         self.b = b
        
    def setter(self, value = 0, 
              start = 0, end = 1):
        prop = locals()['self']
        if start <= value <= end:
            return value
        else:
            raise ValueError()
        
    @property
    def b(self): return self._b
    
    @b.setter
    @setter
    def b(self, value):
        pass
    
    @property
    def a(self): return self._a
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value): 
        self._a = self.setter(value)
 
t = A(a = .2, b = 0)
print(t.a)
```